# Get ID for each connection in the program for each "computer"

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I hope I can explain myself. I have a table with PK integer with autoincrement on MySQL server; and on the client side, two (or more) PCs that with a WinForm program make insertions, updates and queries.

What would happen if?

- PC01 inserts a record.
- PC02 inserts a different record after PC01 does.

But what if when PC01 queries its ID *(SELECT MAX (ID) FROM table)* it would get the ID generated by the record created by PC02?

Considering that you enter the database with a non-root user. What is the best alternative to obtain the proper ID for each connection on each pc? What should I add or consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MAX to find the latest ID when more than one client could insert at the same time is a huge mistake. Use the LAST_INSERT_ID() function

For example, suppose you insert into a Customers table that has an AUTOINCREMENT column and a Name column

```
string SQLText = "INSERT INTO Customers (Name) VALUES (@name);SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(.....))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLText,cn))
{
   cn.Open();
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Steve";
   int lastID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   ....
}
```

The important thing here is the fact that LAST_INSERT_ID returns the autogenerated value for the connection that calls it. In this way, if you have two connections each one has its own id returned

As commented below by `Bradley Grainger`, MySql provides a 'not-standard' property called `LastInsertedId` from the `MySqlCommand` class and this property contains the same value that you could get from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. I have a mixed feelings about this property. From a certain point of view it is very handy, but if you ever plan to change the database then you need a different ado.net library and you will not have that comodity available and you need again some kind of 'custom' function to get the same result (for example `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for Sql Server).

Comment: Thanks. Put `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the same string forces the server to execute the client that requests it, right ?

Comment: MySql could execute the so called "batch updates" meaning that you can put two or more sql statements in a single string separating the statements with a semicolon. All the statements will be executed and the last one being a select of a single value will be returned by the ExecuteScalar

Comment: `MySqlCommand` has a `LastInsertedId` property that will be populated (after an `INSERT`) even if you don't add `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to the SQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_LastInsertedId.htm

Comment: That's interesting. It could be useful albeit I think it is not standard for a class that implements the IDbCommand interface, (oh well anything about autoincrement columns is not really standardized)

Comment: Correct; it's an addition to `IDbCommand` (and `DbCommand`), so you can only access it if you're explicitly using a `MySqlCommand` object. (I saw your example code was using `MySqlCommand`, which is why I mentioned it.)